Visibility of external tables in CROSS APPLY
It would seem that the value from a row in an external dataset should be visible internally. Working example:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_2 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 2 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 5 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 col_id, 7 val FROM dual
),
table_3 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 2 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 5 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 col_id, 7 val FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                 FROM table_2 t2
                WHERE t2.col_id in (SELECT t2.col_id
                                      FROM table_3 t3
                                     WHERE t2.col_id = t1.col_id));

But for some reason, in the case of a recursive query, I encountered a visibility problem. Not working example:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_parents AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 col_id, 4 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.col_id
     , uptimate_parent.parent_id
  FROM table_1 t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT parent_id
                 FROM (select col_id, parent_id FROM table_parents WHERE parent_type = 'manager') pars
                WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
                START WITH pars.col_id = t1.col_id
              CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR pars.parent_id = pars.col_id) uptimate_parent;

This code will throw an error:

[42000][904] ORA-00904: "T1"."COL_ID": invalid identifier

He swears at the using it inside CROSS APPLY. What do I misunderstand in the CROSS APPLY logic here? Why in the second case does the subquery not see the value from the row at the place where the subquery is called?
What’s interesting is that by simply moving the CROSS APPLY subquery to the SELECT list, the query becomes fully functional (yes, it’s no coincidence that there is only one highest parent in the test data). That is, this query is quite working:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_parents AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 col_id, 4 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.col_id
     , (SELECT parent_id
          FROM (select col_id, parent_id FROM table_parents WHERE parent_type = 'manager') pars
         WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
         START WITH pars.col_id = t1.col_id
       CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR pars.parent_id = pars.col_id) uptimate_parent
  FROM table_1 t1;

p.s. I implemented this query with a join, but I'm interested in understanding what I understand incorrectly about CROSS APPLY.

The "not working" code appears to work fiddle

@MTO, in my real DB it doesn't work. My Oracle version 12C, I don't see such option in dbfiddle to compare.

CROSS APPLY was only introduced in Oracle 12 and there may be bugs in the initial implementation. You can try patching your database to the latest patch (which may fix some bugs); or contacting My Oracle Support (under your support contract) to see if they can give you a patch that fixes the issue; or upgrade to Oracle 18 or later. However, trying to work out why something doesn't work that appears to have been fixed in later versions seems pointless as the answer is probably "its a bug with that version".

@MT0 I will be satisfied with this answer as well. I just want to understand what the reason is, I don't necessarily have to implement it this way :)
